# Why is scanf and printf value different?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

In my program:

```
int row,col,srow,scol,erow,ecol;
while(scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&row,&col,&srow,&scol,&erow,&ecol)!=EOF){
    int m[row][col];
    ...
}
```

Inside the while loop I used scanf to input values, the values are 4 5 6, and the input works.

```
    for(int x=0;x<row;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<col;y++){
            scanf("%d",&m[row][col]);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to output the value, the values become different, it change to **6422232 6422228 6422224**, and my printf code is like this:

```
for(int a=srow;a<=erow;a++){
        for(int b=scol;b<ecol;b++){
            printf("%d ",m[a][b]);
        }
        printf("%d\n",m[a][ecol]);
    }
```

Why is the problem happen?

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from scanf().

Comment: In the second snippet iteration variables are x and y, but you are scanning into row[col]

Answer (score 2):

You're not taking the input correctly. It should be:

```
for(int x=0;x<row;x++){
     for(int y=0;y<col;y++){
         scanf("%d",&m[x][y]);
     }
}
```

Your output numbers are garbage values that haven't taken values from the input loop.